# In OLS is it methodologically correct to use the variance of a variable as an explanatory variable?

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares, uncertainty

Are some OLS assumptions not satisfied if I use the variance of a variable as a proxy of uncertainty in a regression? For instance, would it be methodologically correct if I use moving averages of rainfall and moving averages of the variance of rainfall in a regression were the dependent variable is production at the farm level? I have not found examples of regressions containing the variance of a variable in the X's so I wonder if that is because there are some modeling issues with that approach.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the standard assumptions of OLS (normality, independence of error and explanatory, iid ) are satisfied, it's not a problem to do it that way. But just be careful how you interpret coefficients to those variable.

Or you can run moving window OLS and allow varying coefficients over time. In this case, you don't need the variance variable.